# Finding number of ways a piece on a chess board can move with number and type of moves given

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, chess

This is the dynamic programming problem I encountered on a site. I solved the problem with the algorithm mentioned below. Though the answers I got were right, the evaluation shows that the Time limit exceeds.

The problem is, on an N*N board, a piece is at a location (xp,yp).It can move to (xd,yd) if and only if abs(xd-xp)+abs(yd-yp) <= S. The piece has to make M moves.  The problem gives N,S, M and (xp,yp) and I have to find how many ways the piece can make M moves on this board.

My solution was as follows.

```
Matrix m0 is initialized with all 0s except with 1 in the location (xp,yp)

Make a N*N matrix m1 for one move from an initialized matrix m0

Make a N*N matrix m2 for two moves from matrix m1

... carry on till m moves and the sum of elements of the final matrix mm 
gives me the number of ways the piece can make M moves on the N*N board 
with given distance constraint S.
```

My pseudocode for calculating a matrix is as follows

```
for each element (e) in matrix m, 

consider the elements (es) in S*S (S is the distance constraint 
given in the problem) box surrounding the elements.

If (abs(es.x-e.x) + abs(es.y-e.y)) <= S, 
then m[e.x][e.y] = m[e.x][e.y] + m[es.x][es.y]. 

(adding the # of ways that es can be reached with number of ways that e can be reached 
 so that position of e in the matrix contains # of ways that e can be reached from es)

In the S*S box, I considered all  elements except the current element e.
```

As per my understanding, the above solution is (N^2)*(S^2) and runs slow though it gives the correct answer. Please suggest an idea of implementing this in N^2 time. Since it involves a 2D board, I presume it can't be done in O(N) time, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Note that the board is symmetric, so you only really need to work with 1/8th of it (not sure if this will result in a sufficient time reduction with your current algorithm though).

Answer (score 0):

The key to this type of problem is to reuse partial results by using a sliding window.

For example, suppose you knew the sum of elements 1 to 1000 of an array X was 1234, and wanted to know the sum of elements 2 to 1001.  The fast way is to compute 1234+X[1001]-X[1].

In this problem, your constraint on the absolute value means that you are trying to add all the values in a diamond shape.

If we now slide the window one step diagonally, we can compute the new sum by adding on the values on the bottom left, and taking away the ones on the top left:

```
..A..    ..-..   .....
.AAA.    .--A.   ...B.
..A.. -> ..A++ = ..BBB
.....    ...+.   ...B.
```

In the diagram we are adding the values marked with +, and taking away the values marked with -.

This has reduced the number of operations from O(S^2) to O(S) to compute each new value.

However, you can do even better as you can use the same trick to precompute the sum of values along each diagonal.  This then lets you compute each new value in O(1).

Comment: thanks for the idea. I have to use precomputed values somehow to reduce the runtime. However, in my case, when I reach a new index on the board, I am checking the positions of indices in square box around it and then updating the current positions value with sum of values in positions that match the contraint (abs(x-x1)+abs(y-y1) <= S). That is, I am not updating any of the positions on the square box except the one in the middle. So, I am not able to understand how I can use precomputed values in my case.

Comment: You are presumably using dynamic programming to compute DP[t][x][y] = number of ways of getting to square x,y at time t.  In this case, for each new time t, you need to compute N^2 values (for each x,y) and so you can use the sliding window to compute these values in O(N^2) instead of O(N^2.S^2).  Note that you need to regenerate the sums along each diagonal at each new time step.